# Detect client disconnect in Server Sent Events in Java

Tags: java, server-sent-events

I have SSE rest application, and am using `PrintWriter` to flush the data to the client. I do use `PrintWriter checkError()` method to determine client is available or not, but it does not report error when client connection (Wi-Fi) goes away, and still thinks client is still connected.

Is there a way in Server Sent Events using Java API which I could leverage to figure out client has been disconnected in case of Half open connections, so that I could close that streaming channel.

Comment: Just wondering: what happens when you continue to write in that channel?

Comment: "write" method is not throwing any error, or exception

Comment: But at some point there must be some sort of socket-based communication that really sends data over the wire. Do you have any idea what happens there?

Comment: `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();  response is type of HttpServletResponse
out.print("id: " + "ServerTime" + "\n");
out.print("data: " + new Date().toLocaleString() + "\n\n");
System.out.println("Error or not " + out.checkError());
out.flush();`

Comment: I am having the same problem. My server polls my database every second and writes to the PrintWriter when a certain change is made. This works but when I close the browser or tab the the server still polls the database needlessly. I tried closing the EventSorce on the client side when `window.onbeforeunload` is called but this doesnt seem to work for me.

Comment: Hi, in our application we define a timeout and we handle reconnection in client application. It isn't the best solution, but for our, it works.